# Performing select operation on a on a non-ranked balanced binary search tree

Tags: ranking, avl-tree

the select function returns int, and should work in O(log n).

my friend got asked this question in an interview and he couldn't answer it,
and i also have no idea how it is possible if the tree isn't ranked,
the interviewer mentioned that the return value of select should somehow help in the solution.

(select takes a rank as a parameter and returns the number in the tree that has this rank)